# Proof that second Frechet derivative is symmetric?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

Is there a "nice" way to prove that the second Frechet derivative of a function between normed spaces is symmetric? Any proofs that I've managed to find seem quite messy and don't really give any intuition for why that is.

Comment: There is essentially one prove that directly generalizes the proof in 2D. It is indeed messy, but it boils down to a double application of the mean value theorem for Gateaux derivatives.